# Помогите создать массив объектов класса на Python

Tags: python, ооп

Мне нужно создать класс студент в котором минимум 5 полей
Потом создать массив объектов класса
Вот что у меня получилось 
Не пойму как это сделать[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `массив = [student_1, student_2, student_3]`

Comment: @andreymal да не, мне нужно в методе Create_list_methode создавать список объектов класса студент (student_1, student_2 и т.д.)

Comment: типо через append
но в результате у меня такой массив: [<__main__.Student object at 0x104d8ba10>]

Comment: Нормальный массив, что-то не так?

Comment: @Ivan Вы видите репрезентацию объекта (метод `__repr__`).

Comment: @nomnoms12 простите не понимаю

Comment: @Ivan Зайду с другой стороны. А что Вы желаете увидеть при печати списка? Я не знаю, `Python` — тоже, поэтому он и показывает Вам `<class object at>` — стандартную репрезентацию класса, которую обычно используют в целях отладки. Вы можете переопределить метод `__repr__` и возвращать такую строку, которую хотите. Но вопрос то не в этом, а в том, как создать массив экземпляров класса. Вы это сделали.

Comment: @nomnoms12 я не очень шарю, поэтому и задал вопрос
вы так умно написали, что я ничего не понял
мне нужно мой метопы Create_list_methode переименовать в __repr__???

Comment: @Ivan Скажите, что хотите увидеть при печати списка, и я с примерами объясню, как это сделать.

Comment: @nomnoms12 я прочитал документацию, там пишет что нужно создать 2 метода: 1- __str__ , а второй - __repr__
Так вот я не понимаю как мне их создать (вернее что в них прописывать)
Был бы очень рад если бы вы мне подсказали, что там нужно прописать)

Comment: @Ivan Так что Вы увидеть то хотите? Третий раз пытаюсь узнать :) От этого ведь ответ зависит. Пожалуйста, приведите пример.

Comment: @nomnoms12 хочу в методе create_list_methode создать массив из моих объектов класса и чтобы при выводе на экран был такой результат: [student_1, student_2, student_3] а не [<__main__.Student object at 0x104d8ba10>] вот это

Comment: @nomnoms12 вообще вот задание лабораторной:
Мне нужно создать класс Student в котором есть 5 полей
Потом создать массив объектов класса (это мои student_1, student_2, student_3)
И потом отсортировать этот массив за одним из полей

Comment: @Ivan Массив `[<__main__.Student object at ...>, <__main__.Student object at ...>, <__main__.Student object at ...>]` — это и есть массив экземпляров класса. Так и должно быть. Если Ваша цель — сделать лабораторную, так и оставьте.

Comment: @nomnoms12 ага, понял
а не подскажите как мне тогда дальше работать с таким массивом, ведь мне нужно его отсортировать

Comment: @Ivan Можете использовать функцию `sorted`, изменив параметр `key`. Сейчас приведу пример.

Comment: @Ivan, главная проблема у вас в том, что в вашем вопросе нет текстового представления вашей программы, а только снимок экрана. Иначе вы бы уже давно получили полный ответ.

Comment: @MarianD да я хотел в виде кода, но мне постоянно пишет мол неправильно отредактированный вопрос ( я пол часа с ним игрался)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import operator

# Дополните нужными полями и методами
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


student_1 = Student('Guido')
student_2 = Student('Steve')
student_3 = Student('Nomnoms12')

objects = [student_1, student_2, student_3]                # Список экземпляров класса Student
result = sorted(objects, key=operator.attrgetter('name'))  # Сортировка по атрибуту name

for student in result:
    print(student.name)
```

***stdout:***

```py
Guido
Nomnoms12
Steve
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ
я наконец все понял!!!
Очень помогли